# Mysql query to get distinct row with column having null and duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

So I have a weird situation in which I have a table like this :

```
mysql> select * from test;
+-------+------+
| name  | sal  |
+-------+------+
| agent | 1000 |
| agent | 2000 |
| NULL  | 3000 |
| NULL  | 4000 |
| smith | 5000 |
| smith | 6000 |
| neo   | 7000 |
+-------+------+
```

I want to return a data set which looks like this :

```
+-------+------+
| name  | sal  |
+-------+------+
| agent | 1000 |
| NULL  | 3000 |
| NULL  | 4000 |
| smith | 5000 |
| neo   | 7000 |
+-------+------+
```

Meaning I want to fetch unique rows wherever name is duplicated, but fetch all rows as it is when name is null or is not duplicated.

I have written this query below in order to achieve that and it works fine. But I want to optimize it.

```
select * 
from test 
where sal in (
                select sal from ( 
                        select min(sal) as sal 
                        from test 
                        group by name 
                    union 
                        select sal 
                        from test where name is null 
                ) t 
order by sal);
```

**Queries for creating this sample data -**

```
create table test (name text, sal int);
insert into test values ('agent',1000);
insert into test values ('agent',2000);
insert into test values (null,3000);
insert into test values (null,4000);
insert into test values ('smith',5000);
insert into test values ('smith',6000);
insert into test values ('neo',7000);
```

Can anyone help me with that? I know that we shouldn't use IN to fetch data because that will increase the query time a lot in production.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use two queries with `UNION ALL` one is for name which value `is null`, another one writes `MIN` aggregate function by name with name isn't `NULL`.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT name,sal
  FROM test
  WHERE name IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name,min(sal)
  FROM test
  WHERE name IS NOT NULL
  group by name
)t1
ORDER BY sal;
```

| name | sal |
| --- | --- |
| agent | 1000 |
|  | 3000 |
|  | 4000 |
| smith | 5000 |
| neo | 7000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJK199i4jgtRVdAeYcYPo4/1)

**Note**

You can try to create an index on `name` column which might help you improve the query performance